# Where are SageMaker runtime Environment Variables explained?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

There are multiple environment variables have been pre-set and available in the SageMaker runtime during training and serving. Where are they defined and explained?

The [SageMaker SDK documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) says:

> For the exhaustive list of available environment variables, see the [SageMaker Containers documentation](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-containers#list-of-provided-environment-variables-by-sagemaker-containers).

However, the documentaion says:

> WARNING: **This package has been deprecated**. Please use the SageMaker Training Toolkit for model training and the SageMaker Inference Toolkit for model serving.

And [SageMaker Inference Toolkit](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-inference-toolkit) does not list them, apparently.

These typical obsolete documentations not updated by the SageMaker team cause so much time to spend. Does AWS not have internal documentation update process?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the links to the official documentation that were requested in the question:

- [Training toolkit environment variables](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit/blob/master/ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.md)
- [Inference toolkit environment variables](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-inference-toolkit/blob/master/src/sagemaker_inference/environment.py)
- [Interference toolkit parameters](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-inference-toolkit/blob/master/src/sagemaker_inference/parameters.py)

Comment: This post should not be down voted and should not be deleted for being link-only.  The question requests official documentation links and this answer provides them.  This is the good type of link-only answer.  See [When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic)